# EaselJS Sprite gotoAndPlay won't loop

Tags: javascript, loops, sprite, easeljs

I used EaselJS to animate a Sprite. I managed to make it move to the right and to the left. The point is I used `gotoAndPlay` to animate my sprite when moving, but my Sprite only does the animation once, then stops on the last frame. I tried to change the frequency, to activate the loop, but nothing works. I hope you can figure out where my mistake is, thank you.
Here is my code:

```
var stage,
img = new Image(),
bg = new Image(),
bgBitmap,
link,
text,
clavier = {
    gauche: 0,
    droite: 0
};

window.onkeydown = keyPress;
window.onkeyup = keyRelease;

function keyPress(e) {
var i;
if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    clavier.gauche = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        link.gotoAndPlay("wkLeft");
    }
}
if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    clavier.droite = 1;
    link.gotoAndPlay("wkRight");
}
}

function keyRelease(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    clavier.gauche = 0;
    link.gotoAndPlay("stand");
}
if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    clavier.droite = 0;
    link.gotoAndPlay("stand");
}
}

function init() {
stage = new createjs.Stage('mon_canvas');

bg.src = "img/bg.png";
bg.onload = creationBg();

img.src = "img/img.png";
img.onload = creationPerso();

createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
}

function creationPerso() {
var ss = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
    images: [img],
    frames: {
        height: 90,
        width: 90,
        regX: 45,
        regY: 45
    },
    animations: {
        wkRight: {
            frames: [5, 9, true, 6],
            speed: 0.1
        },
        stand: [15],
        wkLeft: {
            frames: [0, 4, true, 6],
            speed: 0.1
        }
    }
});
link = new createjs.Sprite(ss, "stand");
link.x = stage.canvas.width / 2;
link.y = 280;
stage.addChild(link);
}

function tick() {
deplacement();
scene.update();
}

function creationBg() {
bgBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(bg);
bgBitmap.regX = 400;
bgBitmap.regY = 300;
bgBitmap.x = 400;
bgBitmap.y = 100;
bgBitmap.scaleX = 1;
bgBitmap.scaleY = 1;
stage.addChild(bgBitmap);
}

function deplacement() {
if (clavier.gauche == 1) {
    link.x = link.x - 1;
}
if (clavier.droite == 1) {
    link.x = link.x + 1;
}

}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Can you include your sprite sheet data? That is likely where the problem lies.

Comment: What do you mean by sprite sheet data ? the var with images, frames and animations ?

Answer (score 0):

Your SpriteSheet format is not correct. You have used the long-form animation format, where `frames` should include a list of frame numbers - but you have used `5,9,true,6` -- which looks like the short form (start, end, next, speed).

Here is a fixed definition using the short form instead.

```
var ss = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
    images: [img],
    frames: {
        height: 90,
        width: 90,
        regX: 45,
        regY: 45
    },
    animations: {
        wkRight: [5, 9, true, 0.1]
        stand: [15],
        wkLeft: [0, 4, true, 0.1]
    }
});
```

Note that if your walk animations are just flipped for left/right, then you can flip the sprite using `scaleX=-1`, reducing the number of frames in your SpriteSheet.

Let me know if that helps. It would also help if you posted a sample, maybe on JSFiddle. Here is a SpriteSheet sample I have used: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/g5epoydb/2/